# Why request a zone file after a domain transfer?

Tags: dns, domain

I recently transferred one of my domains to another company. The new owner has now requested that I also send them a zone file. I've done a little reading about zone files, but am still confused about why another person would request one after a domain transfer.

I can't get any more info from the other people, but would like to learn about this regardless.

In case it matters, the domain contained only a simple Wordpress website, email services, etc.. Nothing fancy. I don't know if they plan on using the old website.

Comment: Whouldn't it a bit easier to ask "that" person what they want? I might try to guess that they asking for NS servers where your current site is running (hosting's name servers). You need to add info in your question - if you transferred your site together with domain or you just move domain out of hosting to another registrar.

Comment: @Alex I would like to understand what a zone file might be used during a domain transfer regardless, but there is also a communication problem at the other end. I will add more info to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain transferring procedure doesn't not require any zone files at all from owner(s). The owner can assign whatever DNS records one want. Domain basically is a product independent from web site. Domain role is pretty simple, - it is association between Key=Value that owner can publish to the world under domain name.

Zone file applies to the people who runs their own DNS server for domain in question, but usually bunch of people simply using registrar's DNS server and assigning via web interface DNS records they need.

When one transferring domain, all one need to do, is to unlock domain to allow transfer and give receiving side unlock code.

If you simply want to help them, you can make a screenshots of your current DNS records in registrar's control panel and give them, but as I said, it IS NOT requirement to finish transferring domain.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to get the zone file, and can't see how it is of any use to them. They said they need it "to point the A-record to the new domain address." I think they are extremely confused?

Comment: Completely agree with you, what is the point to get a domain and point it to IP address of previous owner ? BTW, they can reveal A record with `nslookup` on windows or `dig` on Linux/BSD on any computer.